# Редактирование формул в RichTextBox в Winforms.

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, formula

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что на некоторых ПК не отрывается дефолтный редактор формул. Вопрос в том, как это пофиксить, этот редактор по умолчанию с Виндой идет или Вордом, и в чем может быть проблема?

У меня на ПК все работает, на некторых - не работает, на сколько понял причина именно в этом редакторе.

Comment: В самой операционке такого редактора нет. Очевидно, это компонент Ворда. Естественно, он не будет работать без установленного офисного пакета (более того, этот редактор в новых версиях удален).

Comment: У меня 2016 Ворд, компонент есть, а как тогда редактировать эти формулы в винформах без этого?

Comment: Странно, вы пишите приложение, и используете сторонние компоненты, может вообще ничего в таком случае не писать. А если уже писать, то напишите свой редактор со своими формулами.

Comment: Приложение экспортирует файл в ворд, так что пакет ворда должен быть у всех юзеров, но вот редактор формул не везде работает.

Comment: Я ж написал: этот редактор был удален в новых версиях Ворда. [Equation Editor (Microsoft Equation 3.0) was included in previous versions of Word but has removed from all versions that have installed the January 2018 Public Update (PU).](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/equation-editor-6eac7d71-3c74-437b-80d3-c7dea24fdf3f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Microsoft [посеяли исходники от Microsoft Equation](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/16/microsoft_equation_editor_patched/), при обнаружении дырки один раз пофиксили бинарник на уровне байтов, а потом [решили окончательно забить](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/equation-editor-6eac7d71-3c74-437b-80d3-c7dea24fdf3f). На данный момент предлагается купить <s>такси за 100 баксов</s> сторонний [продукт с недружественной ценовой политикой](https://www.wiris.com/equation_editor/microsoft), чтобы получить возможность редактировать форумлы, созданные в старых Офисах (а также внедряемые через OLE в другие приложения, например, в стандартном контроле Rich Edit).

Некоторыми сторонними разработчиками компонент был залатан и возвращён к жизни:

[**0patch Blog: Micropatching Brings The Abandoned Equation Editor Back To Life**](https://blog.0patch.com/2018/01/bringing-abandoned-equation-editor-back.html)

Инструкции по возрождению компонента включают выковыривание бинарников из старого офиса, изменение реестра, применение патча.

Сам не пользовался, ни за что не отвечаю.